# Python skew function on genome

Tags: python, genome

I am trying to write a skew function for the genome but I am getting the wrong output. Could somebody please tell where am I making a mistake
Here is my code. The sequence I ran was "CATGGGCATCGGCCATACGCC" but the output was

[0:0,1:0,2:0 and so on till 21:0]

```
def SkewArray(Genome):
    SkewArray = {}
    SkewArray[0] = 0
    Genome_list = []
    for char in Genome :
        Genome_list.append(char)
    for index,nucleotide in enumerate(Genome_list) :
        if nucleotide == "A" or "T" :
            SkewArray[index+1] = SkewArray[index]
        elif nucleotide == "G" :
            SkewArray[index+1] = SkewArray[index] + 1
        elif nucleotide == "C" :
            SkewArray[index+1] = SkewArray[index] - 1
    return SkewArray
```

Comment: What is an output you would have expected?

Comment: What the code should have done was to give me an array with positions and the corresponding Cumulative difference between G and C at that position